# How do I search Google in an Android app?

Tags: java, android

I need to create an Android app that searches Google. I use this code:

```
Intent browser=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browser.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com/#q=qwerty"));
startActivity(browser);
```

However, the browser loads the Google home page, whereas I need a page with results of searching for "qwerty".

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do you mean:

```
http://google.com/search?q=qwerty
```